# Is there a way to get auto-import and intellisense for JavaScript projects using Yarn2+?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, yarnpkg-v2

VS Code provides auto-imports and intellisense in JavaScript files in projects using npm.

I know we can use editor SDKs to get intellisense for installed packages in a TypeScript project by using the workspace version. I have tried everything I can, but I cannot find a way to get the default intellisense in JavaScript projects using yarn.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It should work by default

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Thanks. I was thinking something wasn't right. I am going to remove and reinstall yarn and vscode to see if things start working.